# Usage of "neulich" and "in letzter Zeit"

Tags: difference, usage

What is the difference between *neulich* and *in letzter Zeit*? Both mean *recently*.

> 1. Ich habe neulich mit meiner Mutter geredet.
> 2. Ich habe in letzter Zeit mit meiner Mutter geredet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Neulich** is used to point at a single point in time in the past like **the other day**.

**In letzter Zeit** refers to a time span like **in the last weeks** or **lately**.

1. I've talked to my mother the other day.
2. I haven't talked to my mother much lately.  (not exactly your example)